# WinSCP Set GID error

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, winscp

I'm asking this question on behalf of a customer who called into my help desk. He was using WinSCP to try and change permissions of a directories and it's directories. He set RWX for both user and group (nothing for other), he checked the box to set GID so it's subdirectories would inherit the permissions, and he checked the box to change the permissions of the directory and subdirectories recursively. After he pressed ok the permissions did not seem to change, although it works on other folders and he has been able to do this before. Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: Is one of the folders/files below that particular folder owned by another user/group? Then he would not be allowed to change the permissions recursively.

Comment: I was thinking that, because I got that error when I tried to recreate  it on one of my own folders, but he never received an error message. It's almost like the server he's connected to isn't receiving all the instructions.

Comment: If the customer is able to reproduce the problem, log file would be useful. Also what protocol is the customer using?